# How to export table schemas in apache phoenix?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I'd like to export the schema of an existing table in apache phoenix. Are there some commands or tools to do the same thing as `show create table TABLE_NAME` in mysql?

thx

Answer (score 4):

Using the Phoenix sqlline tool: `!describe <table>`

Comment: That's not the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works great.

```sql
SELECT column_name
  FROM system.catalog
  WHERE table_name = 'your_table' AND key_seq IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Apache Phoenix is typically used as a SQL front or interface to a NoSQL DB (like Hadoop).  Perhaps it would help if you were more specific about the challenges you are trying to address.

Answer (score -3):

Since "native" HBase is schema-less (you can only specify column families), this is not possible.

Or you could scan some rows to extract columns with types