# How to get a ddl of an existing table using apache pheonix

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

This is possible with oracl sql developer. I want that same functionality in pheonix is that possible
Ddl along with dcl statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to refer to this question
[How to export table schemas in apache phoenix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196133/how-to-export-table-schemas-in-apache-phoenix)

```
!describe <table_id> is a popular
```